# this.evaluate with function parameters for a large reusable function

Tags: javascript, function, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm using this.evaluate this way:

```
myData = this.evaluate(getData);
```

I need to pass two variables to the getData function, but unfortunately that doesn't work like this:

```
myData = this.evaluate(getData(varA,varB));
```

I don't want to call the function like this, as getData is a large function and I need to evaluate this function more often in the script:

```
myData = this.evaluate(function getData(varA,varB) {
// my code...
});
```

So what can I do instead to pass the parameters and still be able to call the function in other parts of the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that in this way:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

var result1, result2;
casper.start().then(function () {
     result1 = casper.evaluate(add, 3, 5);
     result2 = casper.evaluate(add, "Hello", ", World.");
}).then(function () {
    casper.echo('result1: ' + result1);
    casper.echo('result2: ' + result2);
})

casper.run();
```

Output:

```
result1: 8
result2: Hello, World.
```

Comment: @JoshiiStarlet If there is no further question, please remember to accept my answer...